# How to append to an array using a variadic macro?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

I'm trying to eliminate a bunch of boilerplate code by using macros.

Here's what works.  I can replace:

```
int do_register_script(struct context *L)
{
    method_type const _instance_methods[] = {
        {"new", __new},
        {"delete", __delete}
        {NULL, NULL}
    };
    register_type(L, script, _instance_methods, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

with a macro

```
#define do_register_type(name) \
    int do_register_ ## name(struct context *L) \
    { \
        method_type const _instance_methods[] = { \
            {"new", __new}, \
            {"delete", __delete}, \
            {NULL, NULL} \
        }; \
        register_type(L, name, _instance_methods, 0); \
        return 1; \
    }
```

like so:

```
do_register_type(script);
```

which is perfect!

But I also have some that look like this:

```
int do_register_rectangle(struct context *L)
{
    method_type const _instance_methods[] = {
        {"new", __new},
        {"delete", __delete},
        {"area", area},
        {"perimeter", perimeter}
        {NULL, NULL}
    };
    register_type(L, rectangle, _instance_methods, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

And now the above macro doesn't work.

**How can I add another parameter to the macro to support this?**

I'm using C, not C++, so no templates.

UPDATE: Also sometimes the code this is going in uses aliases for the names

```
        {"area", area},
        {"Area", area},
        {"perimeter", perimeter}
        {"Perimeter", perimeter}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want that :

```
#define do_register_type(name, ...) \
    int do_register_ ## name(struct context *L) \
    { \
        method_type const _instance_methods[] = { \
            {"new", __new}, \
            {"delete", __delete}, \
            __VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) \
            {NULL, NULL} \
        }; \
        register_type(L, name, _instance_methods, 0); \
        return 1; \
    }

do_register_type(script);

do_register_type(script, {"area", area}, {"perimeter", perimeter});
```

previous code being in m.c:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -E m.c
# 1 "m.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "m.c"
# 14 "m.c"
int do_register_script(struct context *L) { method_type const _instance_methods[] = { {"new", __new}, {"delete", __delete}, {NULL, NULL} }; register_type(L, script, _instance_methods, 0); return 1; };

int do_register_script(struct context *L) { method_type const _instance_methods[] = { {"new", __new}, {"delete", __delete}, {"area", area}, {"perimeter", perimeter} , {NULL, NULL} }; register_type(L, script, _instance_methods, 0); return 1; };
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I noticed you do not want the prefix '__' for *area* and *perimeter*, contrarily to *new* and *delete* but may be you want it for some other cases, because of that it is not possible to expand automatically and the only way I see is to give explicitly the code to add

Comment: Anyway to avoid that trailing comma in do_register_type?

Comment: Your solution is working pretty well.  It's clear (except for that trailing comma) how to use it.  The macro isn't complex. It supports aliases.

Comment: @010110110101 I removed it using `__VA_OPT__(,)`see my edited answer

Comment: Having a little trouble getting gcc to accept `__VA_OPT__(,)`. I tried --std=c18 and some other dialects.  Any advice?

Comment: I use *gcc* with 'forcing' a version through `-std=`, all depends on what is your gcc version and what you want, if no do not have a 'real' reason to specify the version let your compiler using its 'default' version. But I encourage you to compile using the option `-Wall` at minimum and better `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` to enforce your code

Comment: I'm definitely doing that.  I have the compiler checks pretty well maxed out and the code is pretty tight about sticking to a standard.  Before now, I had it set to `gnu99`.  Still, no good on the `__VA_OPT__(,)` I'll keep at it.

Comment: Got it.  It was me, not the compiler dialect.

Comment: @010110110101 if is generally us rather than the compilers ^^

Answer (score 1):

Looping over lists in preprocessor normally requires generating boilerplate macros, but you can avoid that by using a somewhat weird syntax for lists:

```
do_register_type(script, (area)(perimeter))
```

Here's how you loop over such lists:

```
#define REG_LOOP(seq) REG_END(REG_LOOP_A seq)

#define REG_END(...) REG_END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define REG_END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define REG_LOOP_A(func) REG_LOOP_BODY(func) REG_LOOP_B
#define REG_LOOP_B(func) REG_LOOP_BODY(func) REG_LOOP_A
#define REG_LOOP_A_END
#define REG_LOOP_B_END

#define REG_LOOP_BODY(func) {#func, func},
```

`REG_LOOP((foo)(bar))` will expand to `{"foo", foo}, {"bar", bar},`.

Then you add this macro to `do_register_type`:

```
#define do_register_type(name, seq) \
    int do_register_ ## name(struct context *L) \
    { \
        method_type const _instance_methods[] = { \
            {"new", __new}, \
            {"delete", __delete}, \
            REG_LOOP(seq) \
            {NULL, NULL} \
        }; \
        register_type(L, name, _instance_methods, 0); \
        return 1; \
    }
```

Comment: I was about to warn you to remove the __, but you just did, I hope your answer is what the OP wants (rather than mine), it is not very clear in the question ...